# Is C++ compiler allowed to store function ptr in register before its arguments are evaluated?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, undefined-behavior

My collegues and I were fighting a rather weird bug in an app we're developing. Eventually we got it fixed, but we are still unsure if what the compiler was doing is legit or not.

Assuming we have code like this:

```cpp
class B {
public:
    virtual int foo(int d) { return d - 10; }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    virtual int foo(int d) { return d - 11; }
};

class A {
public:
    A() : count(0) { member = new B;}
    int bar() {
        return member->foo(renew());
    }

    int renew() {
        count++;
        delete member;
        member = new C;
        return count;
    }
private:
    B *member;
    int count;
};

int square() {
    A a;
    cout << a.bar() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The Visual Studio x86 compiler, for function `A::bar`, generates something like this when compiled with `/O1` (You can check the full code on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/iY7RLn)):

```
        push    esi
        push    edi
        mov     edi, ecx
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [edi]  ; eax = member
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR [eax]  ; esi = B::vtbl
        call    int A::renew(void)    ; Changes the member, vtable and esi are no longer valid
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [edi]
        push    eax
        call    DWORD PTR [esi]       ; Calls wrong stuff (B::vtbl[0])
        pop     edi
        pop     esi
        ret     0
```

Is this optimization allowed by the standard or is it an undefined behaviour?
I was unable to get similar assembly with GCC or clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for perfect clarity, here's the [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) document Jarod42 already linked, and the relevant quote:

> 14) In a function-call expression, the expression that names the function is sequenced before every argument expression and every default argument.

So we should read the statement

```
return member->foo(renew());
```

as

```
return function-call-expression;
```

where *function-call-expression* is

```
{function-naming-expression member->foo} ( {argument-expression renew()} )
```

so, the *function-naming-expression* `member->foo` is *sequenced-before* the argument expression. The doc already linked says

> If A is sequenced before B, then evaluation of A will be complete before evaluation of B begins.

so we have to completely evaluate `member->foo` first. I think it should expand like

```
// 1. evaluate function-naming-expression
auto tmp_this_member = this->member;
int (B::*tmp_foo)(int) = tmp_this_member->foo;

// 2. evaluate argument expression
int tmp_argument = this->renew();

// 3. make the function call
(tmp_this_member->*tmp_foo) ( tmp_argument );
```

... which is exactly what you see. This is the sequencing required by C++17, and prior to that the sequencing and behaviour were both undefined.

---

**tl;dr** the compiler is right, and that code would be nasty even if it worked.

Comment: Agree on all counts. Even if the ordering were guaranteed to be what the OP wanted (which it never was, and is certainly not since C++17), that's flaky code! Jarod's final example is perfect.

Comment: Also agreed on every point. Unfortunately, this means that GCC with -O2 is completely wrong as the code it produces works but should not work instead.

Comment: I suspect that since this code produces UB with C++17 sequencing, the optimizer isn't required to ensure the result is sane. That is, calling a method on `tpm_this_member` after its deletion is illegal, so the optimizer can reorder the loads as if it never happened.

Comment: You have a totally legit point that makes perfect sense. So to summirize all, don't write nasty code.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas order of evaluation is implementation specific prior to C++17, C++17 imposes some ordering, see [evaluation order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

so in

```
this->member->foo(renew());
```

`renew()` might be called before evaluating `this->member` (prior C++17).

To guaranty order prior, C++17, you have to split into several different statement:

```
auto m = this->member;
auto param = renew(); // m is now pointing on deleted memory
m->foo(param);        // UB.
```

or, for the other order:

```
auto param = renew();
this->member->foo(param);
```

Comment: Are you saying that in C++17 the compiler _must_ fully evaluate `renew()` first? If so, it must mean that the Visual Studio compiler has a bug in it, or simply not compatible with C++17.

Comment: @GrimMaple: Rechecking order of C++17.

Comment: "In a function-call expression, the expression that names the function is sequenced before every argument expression and every default argument." ... does that mean the expression `member` _must_ be evaluated before the arguments are, and therefore before `this->member` is mutated?

Comment: Actually, I just compiled the same code with GCC (no optimization) and it stores `member` in `r12` before evaluating the `renew()` [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s6yV6M) . So it might be strictly defined by C++17 standard to do so.

Comment: I meant, in C++17, `this->member` should be evaluated before `renew()` (leading to UB as dereferencing deleted pointer).

Comment: @Useless, your comment is the key in my opinion. It means that foo is resolved before any argument evaluation. Since member was pointing to a B object, the foo call will resolve to B::foo. After this, as a side effect of the call to renew() during argument evaluation, member will point to a C object just before executing B::foo, but it won't impact the previous resolution. Hence B::foo will be used whatever member points to now.

Comment: @Jarod42 Or using a dangling pointer, really. (Right? (At least semantically. (In practice the dereference comes with the member access during the call. (So in practice it's a bad dereference as you say. (Wow lispy)))))